# Proper initialization of an arraylist in an object?

Tags: java, arraylist, initialization

Assuming that I'm running with an object like this like this:

```
static class fileHandler {
    File fileToHandle;
    ArrayList fileDetails;

    fileHandler(File fileIn) {
        fileToHandle = fileIn;
    }


    public void fileHandling() {

        try {
            Scanner reader = new Scanner(fileToHandle);
            reader.useDelimiter(",");
            while(reader.hasNext()) {
                String s = reader.next();
                fileDetails.add(s);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { System.err.println("File Not Found!"); }
    }
}
```

How could I make "fileDetails" able to work inside my method?

Comment: Just instantiate a new object of fileDetails type inside your method. `fileDetails = new ArrayList<T>();`

Comment: Also it's good to note that unless you have a specific reason for referring `fileDetails` from a concrete class, then it's far better to refer to `List` instead. Makes your programs more flexible.

Answer (score 2):

Initialize it in your Constructor

```
fileHandler(File fileIn) {
    fileToHandle = fileIn;
    fileDetails = new ArrayList();
}
```

or right on definition:

```
ArrayList fileDetails = new ArrayList();
```

By the way you should use a generic ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<String> fileDetails = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and class names should start with a Uppercase Letter

```
class FileHandler {
```

Comment: Also declare your class fields `final`, and use getters to access them.

Comment: @ortang probaby ment `private` instead of `final`

Comment: @ortang defining fields as `private final` in this case would be utterly stupid. He does not need his class to be immutable. It would be silly.

Comment: Why not? I see no reason why `fileDetails` or `fileToHandle` should change after he created a instance of the class. I have no idea if he wants his class immutable, plus only adding `final` does not make that class immutable.

Comment: in his case it would make it immutable. Since he only has two fields. `fileDetails` and `fileToHandle`. And by definition `Immutable means unchangeable. In Java, when an object is defined as being immutable it means that once it has been initialized its state cannot be changed.`

Comment: That's only true for `fileToHandle` since instances of the `File` class are immutable. However `fileDetails` is a instance of `ArrayList` and that class is not immutable. You could wrap `fileDetails` with `Collections.unmodifiableList(fileDetails)` in a getter method. But then again that makes no sense because his class in an inner class and the outer class can always access the internal fields, so there is no way to make that class immutable.